# Compare a Vec with a Range in rust

Tags: rust

I want to check if a `Vec` is equal to `[0, 1, 2, ...]`. I've tried various variants of:

```
vec == &(0..vec.len())
```

But none of them seem to work. Do I just have to write a loop out long-hand?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use iterators to compare a `Vec<T>` (or more generally, a slice `[T]`) to a range ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=399f9d14c13d5a45ff8a3690bd579b6d&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)):

```
let v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

if v.iter().cloned().eq(0..v.len()) {
    println!("v contains 0..5");
} else {
    println!("v doesn't contain 0..5");
}
```

Let's dissect the important part:

```
v.iter().cloned().eq(0..v.len())
```

- `v.iter()` creates an iterator over references to the elements in the vector (`Iterator<Item = &{integer}>`).
- [`.cloned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned) clones each element in the iterator to go from reference to owned value. This is required because we cannot compare `&{integer}` to `{integer}`. Luckily, cloning a simple integer is basically free. So now we have `Iterator<Item = {integer}>`.
- [`.eq` is a method of `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.eq) which compares the iterator to another iterator.
- `0..v.len()` is an range from 0 (inclusive) to `v.len()` (exclusive). [Such a range implements `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/struct.Range.html#implementations).

Comment: Thanks!

 I've just corrected my question (I differed in two places if I wanted 0..len-1, or 1..len. I wanted 0..len-1). You might want to make your answer sync up with that (sorry!)

Comment: @ChrisJefferson Updated.